# How to remove part of href tag from links using jquery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, amp-html

I need to make all html links of my wordpress website dont end in "?amp=1".

For example the link:

```
<a href="https://example.com/page-1/?amp=1">Page 1</a>
```

It should change to:

```
<a href="https://example.com/page-1/">Page 1</a>
```

I have added the following code to my functions.php file but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```html
function remove_amptoamp_links(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').each(function(){
   if(this.href.indexOf("?amp=1") != -1)
   {
       var href=this.href.split("?amp=1")[0];
       this.href = href;
   }
    });
});
</script>';
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_amptoamp_links');
```

Some help? Thanks!

Comment: You code works just fine, please check if you get any errors in your console.

Comment: You must have a plug-in that adds this. It's not part of core

Comment: Are you using official WordPress plugin for AMP?

Comment: Yes, I use the official AMP plugin.

The posts work correctly in the AMP version but I want that if someone clicks on a link, it will take them to the full version of the website. (Like the big news sites do.)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally discovered that AMP does not allow Javascript to be executed.